# Unexpected sizeof(class) difference between Cython and Visual Studio Project compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, python-3.x, cython

My `cython` project generates correct cpp (compared to working examples) but crashes in a `new` call. I have debugged it down to a difference is the `size_t size` inside new. A different working CPP project generates a size of 248 and the python code 240. Since they both link to other DLLs the size needs to be the same. The working project is compiled for debug and I wold like the `cython` project to do the same. I need to understand why class size packing is different and how to fix it!

Below are more details:

I'm trying to wrap a C++ library in a cython file called `tip.pyx`. I am using Cython 0.20.2, Visual Studio 2010 and Python3.4 (32 bit). I have a working Visual Studio 2010 project (compiled for debug) that I'm comparing the results to.

The cython generated `tip.cpp` code does the "correct" thing (i.e it mimics the calls a working Visual Studio project file does) as can be seen below.

The cython code throws an exception during the `new HDMISource(...)` call. I have debugged that the parameters passed into the call are the same as the working C++ example.

The only difference I can see is that the `new` operator receives a difference `size_t size` when using the cython path. (240 for "cython" and 248 for the working visual studio).

Both are using the same compilers (VS2010). The working example is compiled through a Visual Studio project and the other through `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

My `setup.py` for cython is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext = Extension("tip", ["tip.pyx"], language="c++",
                define_macros=[('USE_HAPS6ENV', '1'),
                               ('WIN32', '1'),
                               ('NDEBUG', '1'),
                               ('_WINDOWS', '1'),
                               ('_USRDLL', '1'),
                               ('TIP_EXPORTS', '1')],
                include_dirs=['C:/Projects/TIP_SW/Include/',
                              'C:/Projects/TIP_SW/Include/HDMI/',
                              'C:/Projects/TIP_SW/Source/Include/'],
                libraries=['Haps6Env', 'CoreEnv', 'HDMI'],
                library_dirs=['C:/Projects/TIP_SW/Bin/Debug'],
                extra_compile_args=['-Zi', '/Od'],
                extra_link_args=['-debug'])


setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=[ext],
)
```

For reference the none working cython code (auto comments removed):

```
static int __pyx_pf_3tip_12PyHDMISource___cinit__(struct __pyx_obj_3tip_PyHDMISource *__pyx_v_self, std::string __pyx_v_pin_map) {
  TipUserEnvironmentInterface *__pyx_v_env;
  int __pyx_r;
  __Pyx_RefNannyDeclarations
  __Pyx_RefNannySetupContext("__cinit__", 0);

  __pyx_v_env = GetHapsTipEnvironment();
  __pyx_v_self->thisptr = new HDMISource(__pyx_v_pin_map, __pyx_v_env);
```

The working Visual Studio Cpp code:

```
TipUserEnvironmentInterface* env = GetEnvironment();
HDMISource* myTx = new HDMISource("MyPinsTx", env);
```

The `__pyx_v_env` and `env` pointers are "the same" after the `GetEnvironment()` call (tested by stepping through code). When I step into the `new` method (into `new.cpp`) I end up at the following code. In the working case `size_t size` is 248 and for the `cython` path it's 240:

```
void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)
    {       // try to allocate size bytes
    void *p;
    while ((p = malloc(size)) == 0)
            if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
            {       // report no memory
            static const std::bad_alloc nomem;
            _RAISE(nomem);
            }

    return (p);
    }
```

The result is that when using `cython` the allocated space is not enough so that internal variables (i.e the passed in pointed) gets whacked resulting in an exception later in the code.

This seem to indicate a difference in packing (debug vs none debug?). What should change during cython compile to make the class packing the same? The project is dependent on multiple compiled DLLs and we mostly use the `debug` solution.

Comment: Are you compiling both with the same bitness?

Comment: @T.C I don't know what `same bitness` means but yes they are both 32 bits (I don't have 64 bits installed.

Comment: So for kicks I created a Visual Studio Project and sucked in the generated C++ file and generate a .pyd file this way and it now works. So there is some compile or linker switch that I need to add to my `setup.py` to make it work. I don't know what yet. Hope someone else can help out!

Comment: So it's the sizeof(HDMISource) that differs in the two versions, right? Are there any ifdef lines in the HDMISource class definition? Is that class under your control? Can you modify it if necessary?

Comment: Sorry. I saw you message in a meeting and then it slipped my mind. There are no ifdefs in that particular file and I do set the "system wide" if refs the same. I have still not found a solution to this answer but I have also given up since it works running Visual Studio (from the command line). I now use `cython` to generate the file and then `devenv` to compile the visual studio project. Still a little strange to me